# JQuery function after addClass() on class added

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
$('#closecallout').click(function() {
    $('.callout').animate({"right" : "-260px"}, 500).addClass('calloutclosed');
});
$('.calloutclosed').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"right" : "0px"}, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({"right" : "-260px"}, 500);
});
```

The click function is meant to 'hide' the callout box, and then afterwards, when hovered, it will move back into focus.

Why does the hover function not work?  Is it because these are both within a `jQuery(function($){ });` ?

What steps should I take to rectify this?

http://jsfiddle.net/R5Dmu/

Many thanks SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get events to trigger on elements based on their current class you'll need to use event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('#closecallout').click(function() {
    $('.callout').animate({"right" : "-260px"}, 500).addClass('calloutclosed');
});
$(document).on('mouseover', '.calloutclosed', function() {
    $(this).animate({"right" : "0px"}, 500);
}).on('mouseout', '.calloutclosed', function() {
    $(this).animate({"right" : "-260px"}, 500);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Dmu/1/)

Comment: @NorbertPisz what does that mean?

Comment: Try to hover and unhover fast many times and watch for effect.

Comment: @NorbertPisz that's normal

Comment: They both work and do the exact same thing.  Very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When You call click function You need to add class and implement hover function. In your code You added class on click event but not implement hover function. You implement hover function on document ready and then Jquery could find selector with calloutclosed class becouse is not click event yet.

Check this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

//CALLOUT
$('#closecallout').click(function () {
    $('.callout').animate({
        "right": "-260px"
    }, 500)
    $('.callout').addClass('calloutclosed');

    $('.calloutclosed').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "right": "0px"
        }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "right": "-260px"
        }, 500);
    });

});
});
```

Comment: The code works, but how about a shot explanation? Also please format your answers correctly. It's quite hard to read in it's current form.

Comment: great! Your post looks much better now :) Also I'm not the one who asked the question :)